# Different Timestamp captured in Google Form and App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a use case where i need to get the timestamp for the form responses (and string it) and email to respondent.

Here is my code and i would like to ensure it's exactly the same as Timestamp in my sheet

Code

```
Logger.log("e.response.getTimestamp()" + e.response.getTimestamp()) ;
```

Screenshot of the respondent (sorry for couldn't post image yet)
[Screenshot of the respondent](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jukDvMJErgl2qs5NQ00OFAvgqqJVeN4z/view?usp=drivesdk)

Questions
 - How come the timing is 1 second different?
 - How could i string it (in both form and app string) so i can get identical result

Comment: What did you got in log ?

Comment: Rounding issue? What value is shown in the Google Sheets formula bar? As Umair said, what did you got in log?

Comment: To avoid rounding, try using valueOf() or getTime() instead.

Comment: @Umair, here the log[18-02-02 17:15:07:287 HKT] Logger.log([e.response.getTimestamp().toISOString() 2018-02-02T09:15:05.933Z, []]) [0 seconds]
[18-02-02 17:15:07:288 HKT] Logger.log([e.response.getTimestamp()    Fri Feb 02 2018 17:15:05 GMT+0800 (HKT), []]) [0 seconds]

and Cooper, it wasn't a rounding issue, something new to me as i thought timezone only different is HOUR field, but fortunately, i am able to create custom JS func in sheet, to convert Timestamp into ISO timing, to make the submission time (form) and sheet time identical. Due to char limit will be posted in next comment

Comment: Here the actual sheet, it shown the sec really different in different timezone.
But what i really need, is to get identical string in both form submission and sheet. Thanks God i finally have it!

[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16WsONIJ3-WJISPMxGBKm2Tv9IsuOJ68W)

Comment: I think `Timestamp ISO` is recording time in GMT 00:00 whereas the `Timestamp` records time with respect to owner time zone.[or maybe submitters time zone, not sure]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Google Forms stores internally form responses using milliseconds but when writing the timestamp to Google Sheets the timestamps are rounded to seconds.